# IE7 Compatibility Issue with Navigation Drop-Down (3-Levels) CSS/Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, navigation

I built a CSS/Javascript navigation that has 3-levels. The navigation works perfect in all browsers except IE7. The problem is as follows: If I scroll over the "All Products," then follow the drop-down to New Macs or Used Macs and then mouse out of the navigation to the left; from that point on every time I mouse over "All Products," the background image for the 3rd level shows up without any content. You will see what I mean if you view the website in IE 9 Browser Mode (IE7). Anyways, I could desperately use some help!

Thanks,
DH

Here is nav I am referring to: http://demo2.reclaimdesign.com/testnav2.html

And below is the code.

CSS

```
/* CSS Document */
h5 {font-family:'FranklinGothicLT-BookCnd', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-  size:13px;font-weight:normal;color:#ff8e04;text-transform:uppercase;letter-spacing:-1px;margin:0; }
img{border:none;}

#header
{
position:relative;
z-index:100;
padding-bottom:38px;
}

#nav{width:965px;position:absolute;}

#menu {list-style:none;padding:0;margin:0;}

.menu-item {position:relative;float:left;line-height:30px;}

#menuAllProducts{background:url(../images/nav/all_products.png) no-repeat;width:110px;height:35px;z-index:100;position:relative;text-indent:-9000px;margin-right:4px;}
    #sub-menuAllProducts ul.sub-menu{position:absolute;top:45px;left:0;width:199px;list-style:none;padding:10px 0 0;margin:0;background:#ff8e04;border:solid 1px #a3a3a3;box-shadow:3px 4px 10px -3px #555454;}
    #sub-menuAllProducts li.sub-item{position:relative;height:26px;line-height:30px;padding-left:10px;background:#ff8e04 url(../images/background/nav_dropdown.png) no-repeat;}
    #sub-menuAllProducts li.sub-item:hover{background:#fcba00;color:#fff;}
    #sub-menuAllProducts li.sub-item a, 
    #sub-menuAllProducts li.sub-item a:link,
    #sub-menuAllProducts li.sub-item a:active{color:#fd9b24;text-decoration:none;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-weight:bold;font-size:12px;} 
    #sub-menuAllProducts li.sub-item a:hover{color:#fff;}

    #sub-menuAllProducts #third-menuNewMacs{top:0;right:-470px; width:468px;height:151px;background:url(../images/background/nav_newmacs.png) no-repeat;}
    #sub-menuAllProducts #third-menuNewMacs ul {float:left;margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none;line-height:100%;width:100px;}
    #sub-menuAllProducts #third-menuNewMacs ul.menuMacMini{width:65px;}
    #sub-menuAllProducts #third-menuNewMacs li {height:auto;line-height:20px;color:#595858;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-weight:bold;font-size:12px;text-align:center;}
        #sub-menuAllProducts #third-menuNewMacs li a, 
        #sub-menuAllProducts #third-menuNewMacs li a:link, 
        #sub-menuAllProducts #third-menuNewMacs li a:active{color:#35cffa;text-decoration:none;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-weight:normal;font-size:11px;} 
        #sub-menuAllProducts #third-menuNewMacs li a:hover{color:#35cffa;text-decoration:underline;}

    #sub-menuAllProducts #third-menuNewMacs .arrow{position:absolute;top:0;left:-2px;}
    #sub-menuAllProducts #third-menuUsedMacs{top:-27px;right:-752px;width:750px;}
    #sub-menuAllProducts #third-menuUsedMacs .arrow{position:absolute;top:27px;left:-2px;}

    #sub-menuAllProducts .third-menu {list-style:none;padding:0;margin:0;background:#f7f7f7;border:solid 1px #a3a3a3;box-shadow: 3px 4px 10px -3px #555454;}
    #sub-menuAllProducts .third-menu ul {float:left;margin:0;padding:5px 10px;list-style:none;line-height:100%;width:160px;}
    #sub-menuAllProducts .third-menu li a, 
    #sub-menuAllProducts .third-menu li a:link, 
    #sub-menuAllProducts .third-menu li a:active{color:#6a6a6a;text-decoration:none;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-weight:normal;font-size:11px;} 
    #sub-menuAllProducts .third-menu li a:hover{color:#6a6a6a;text-decoration:underline;}
    #sub-menuAllProducts .third-menu li a, .third-menu li a:link, .third-menu li a:active{color:#6a6a6a;text-decoration:none;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-weight:normal;font-size:11px;} 
    #sub-menuAllProducts .third-menu li a:hover{color:#6a6a6a;text-decoration:underline;}
    #sub-menuAllProducts .third-menu li {height:auto;line-height:20px;color:#595858;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-weight:bold;font-size:12px;}
    #sub-menuAllProducts .third-menu li h5{color:#ff8e04;border-bottom:solid 1px #cbcbca;}

ul.sub-menu {position:absolute;top:45px;left:0;z-index:50;width:199px;list-style:none;padding:10px 0 0;margin:0;display:none;background:#ff8e04;border:solid 1px #a3a3a3;box-shadow: 3px 4px 10px -3px #555454;}
    li.menu-item:hover .sub-menu { display: block; }

li.sub-item {position:relative;height:26px;line-height:30px;padding-left:10px;background:#f7f7f7;}
    li.sub-item:hover { background:#b8b7b6;color:#fff;}
    li.sub-item:hover .third-menu { display: block; }
    li.sub-item a, li.sub-item a:link,li.sub-item a:active{color:#6a6a6a;text-decoration:none;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-weight:bold;font-size:11px;}  
    li.sub-item a:hover{color:#fff;}

.third-menu {position:absolute;top:-27px;right:-752px;width:750px;list-style:none;padding:0;margin:0;display:none;background:#f7f7f7;border:solid 1px #a3a3a3;box-shadow: 3px 4px 10px -3px #555454;}
    .third-menu .bkg{background:#b8b7b6;height:10px;}
    .third-menu ul {float:left;margin:0;padding:5px 10px;list-style:none;line-height:100%;width:160px;}
    .third-menu li {height:auto;line-height:20px;color:#595858;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-weight:bold;font-size:12px;}
    .third-menu li a, .third-menu li a:link, .third-menu li a:active{color:#6a6a6a;text-decoration:none;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-weight:normal;font-size:11px;} 
    .third-menu li a:hover{color:#6a6a6a;text-decoration:underline;}
    .third-menu li h5{color:#ff8e04;border-bottom:solid 1px #cbcbca;}

.stretch,.clear {clear: both;height: 1px;margin: 0;padding: 0;font-size: 15px;line-height: 1px;}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="css/test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/ie7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!-- JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript">
 function changeBackground(oEl, iMode) {
var sId = oEl.id;
if (sId == null) alert("Your Element Does Not Have An ID!");

if ((sId == 'menuAllProducts') || (sId == 'sub-menuAllProducts')) {
    if (iMode == 1) {
        document.getElementById('menuAllProducts').style.backgroundPosition='0px -35px';
        document.getElementById('menuAllProducts').style.height = "46px";
    } else if (iMode == 2) {
        document.getElementById('menuAllProducts').style.backgroundPosition='0px 0px';
        document.getElementById('menuAllProducts').style.height = "35px";
    }
} else if ((sId == 'menuCustomerResources') || (sId == 'sub-menuCustomerResources' ))  {
    if (iMode == 1) {
        document.getElementById('menuCustomerResources').style.backgroundPosition='0px -35px';
        document.getElementById('menuCustomerResources').style.height = "46px";
    } else if (iMode == 2) {
        document.getElementById('menuCustomerResources').style.backgroundPosition='0px 0px';
        document.getElementById('menuCustomerResources').style.height = "35px";
    }
} else if ((sId == 'menuPowerMaxAttitude') || (sId == 'sub-menuPowerMaxAttitude' )) {
    if (iMode == 1) {
        document.getElementById('menuPowerMaxAttitude').style.backgroundPosition='0px -35px';
        document.getElementById('menuPowerMaxAttitude').style.height = "46px";
    } else if (iMode == 2) {
        document.getElementById('menuPowerMaxAttitude').style.backgroundPosition='0px 0px';
        document.getElementById('menuPowerMaxAttitude').style.height = "35px";
    }
} else if ((sId == 'menuShippingPayment') || (sId == 'sub-menuShippingPayment' ))  {
    if (iMode == 1) {
        document.getElementById('menuShippingPayment').style.backgroundPosition='0px -35px';
        document.getElementById('menuShippingPayment').style.height = "46px";
    } else if (iMode == 2) {
        document.getElementById('menuShippingPayment').style.backgroundPosition='0px 0px';
        document.getElementById('menuShippingPayment').style.height = "35px";
    }
} 
}
</script>


</head>

<body>
<div id="header">
 <div id="nav">
   <ul id="menu">
     <li class="menu-item">
   <div id="menuAllProducts" onMouseOver="changeBackground(this, 1);" onMouseOut="changeBackground(this, 2);">  
           <a href="#">All Products</a>
       </div>
       <ul class="sub-menu" id="sub-menuAllProducts"  onMouseOver="changeBackground(this, 1);" onMouseOut="changeBackground(this, 2);">
         <li class="sub-item" onmouseover="document.getElementById('menuNewMacs').style.color= '#FFFFFF'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('menuNewMacs').style.color = '#FF8E04'">
            <a href="#" id="menuNewMacs">New Macs</a>
              <div id="third-menuNewMacs" class="third-menu">
               <div class="bkg"></div>
               <div class="arrow"><img src="images/nav/arrow_head.png" /></div>          
               <div class="newMacsOptions">
             <ul class="menuMacBookPro">
                  <li><img src="images/nav/icons/macbook_pro.png" /></li>
                  <li><a href="#">MacBook Pro: 13"</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">MacBook Pro: 15"</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Macbook Pro: 17"</a></li>
                 </ul>
                 <ul class="menuMacBookAir">
                  <li><img src="images/nav/icons/macbook_air.png" /></li>
                  <li><a href="#">MacBook Air: 11"</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">MacBook Air: 13"</a></li>
                 </ul>
                 <ul class="menuIMac">
                  <li><img src="images/nav/icons/imac.png" /></li>
                  <li><a href="#">iMac: 21.5"</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">iMac: 27"</a></li>
                 </ul>
                 <ul class="menuMacMini">
                  <li><img src="images/nav/icons/mac_mini.png" /></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Mac mini</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Servers</a></li>
                 </ul>
             <ul class="menuMacPro">
                  <li><img src="images/nav/icons/mac_pro.png" /></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Mac Pro</a></li>
                 </ul>
                </div>
               </div>
              </li>
              <li class="sub-item" onmouseover="document.getElementById('menuUsedMacs').style.color= '#FFFFFF'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('menuUsedMacs').style.color = '#FF8E04'">
    <a href="#" id="menuUsedMacs">Used Macs</a>
    <div id="third-menuUsedMacs" class="third-menu">
      <div class="bkg"></div>
      <div class="arrow"><img src="images/nav/arrow_head.png" /></div>
      <ul>
        <li><h5>Desktops / Xserve</h5></li>
        <li><a href="#">Mac Pro</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">G5 Power Mac - PCI-E</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">G5 Power Mac - PCI-x</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">G5 Power Mac - PCI</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">G4 Power Mac Towers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Mac Mini - G4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">XServe - Intel</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">XServe - G5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">XServe - G4</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li><h5>iMacs / eMac</h5></li>
        <li><a href="#">Intel iMac: 27-inch</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Intel iMac: 21.5-inch</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Intel iMac: 24-inch</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Intel iMac: 20-inch</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Intel iMac: 17-inch</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">G5 iMac: 20-inch</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">G5 iMac: 17-inch</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">G4 iMac: 20-inch</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">G4 iMac: 17-inch</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">G4 iMac: 15-inch</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">eMac</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li><h5>MacBook / MacBook Pro</h5></li>
        <li><a href="#">Intel iMac: 27-inch</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Intel iMac: 21.5-inch</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Intel iMac: 24-inch</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Intel iMac: 20-inch</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Intel iMac: 17-inch</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">G5 iMac: 20-inch</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">G5 iMac: 17-inch</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">G4 iMac: 20-inch</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">G4 iMac: 17-inch</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">G4 iMac: 15-inch</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">eMac</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li><h5>iBook / PowerBooks</h5></li>
        <li><a href="#">Intel iMac: 27-inch</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Intel iMac: 21.5-inch</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Intel iMac: 24-inch</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Intel iMac: 20-inch</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Intel iMac: 17-inch</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">G5 iMac: 20-inch</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">G5 iMac: 17-inch</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">G4 iMac: 20-inch</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">G4 iMac: 17-inch</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">G4 iMac: 15-inch</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">eMac</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="sub-item" onmouseover="document.getElementById('menuSpecialValueMacs').style.color= '#FFFFFF'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('menuSpecialValueMacs').style.color = '#FF8E04'">
    <a href="#" id="menuSpecialValueMacs">Special Value Macs</a>
  </li>
  <li class="sub-item" onmouseover="document.getElementById('menuCustomMacs').style.color= '#FFFFFF'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('menuCustomMacs').style.color = '#FF8E04'">
    <a href="#" id="menuCustomMacs">Custom Macs</a>
  </li>
  <li class="sub-item" onmouseover="document.getElementById('menuiPods').style.color= '#FFFFFF'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('menuiPods').style.color = '#FF8E04'">
    <a href="#" id="menuiPods">iPods</a>
  </li>
  <li class="sub-item" onmouseover="document.getElementById('menuiPads').style.color= '#FFFFFF'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('menuiPads').style.color = '#FF8E04'">
    <a href="#" id="menuiPads">iPads</a>
  </li>
  <li class="sub-item" onmouseover="document.getElementById('menuStorage').style.color= '#FFFFFF'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('menuStorage').style.color = '#FF8E04'">
    <a href="#" id="menuStorage">Storage</a>
  </li>
  <li class="sub-item" onmouseover="document.getElementById('menuDisplays').style.color= '#FFFFFF'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('menuDisplays').style.color = '#FF8E04'">
    <a href="#" id="menuDisplays">Displays</a>
  </li>
  <li class="sub-item" onmouseover="document.getElementById('menuVideoAudio').style.color= '#FFFFFF'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('menuVideoAudio').style.color = '#FF8E04'">
    <a href="#" id="menuVideoAudio">Video+Audio</a>
  </li>
  <li class="sub-item" onmouseover="document.getElementById('menuAccessories').style.color= '#FFFFFF'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('menuAccessories').style.color = '#FF8E04'">
    <a href="#" id="menuAccessories">Accessories</a>
  </li>
  <li class="sub-item" onmouseover="document.getElementById('menuNetworking').style.color= '#FFFFFF'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('menuNetworking').style.color = '#FF8E04'">
    <a href="#" id="menuNetworking">Networking</a>
  </li>
  <li class="sub-item" onmouseover="document.getElementById('menuSoftware').style.color= '#FFFFFF'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('menuSoftware').style.color = '#FF8E04'">
    <a href="#" id="menuSoftware">Software</a>
  </li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#"><img src="images/nav/click_to_chat.png" /></a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you need javascript for this? I think it could be done with just css.

Comment: I am sure it could, but I spent sometime trying to build it with CSS only and ended up using javascript to get it to work.

Comment: one question: why is the onmouseover and onmouseout here: <ul class="sub-menu" id="sub-menuAllProducts"  onMouseOver="changeBackground(this, 1);" onMouseOut="changeBackground(this, 2);"> camel cased(onMouseOver instead onmouseover)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gone through your code, and the apparent reason for your problem is that if you move the mouse out of the menu too quickly, the hover style gets stuck. I cannot think of anything that can be done about this root cause, it is a quirk of IE7, and that is that. Some kind of failsafe is needed, and javascript can be used for that. What you need to do is set the CSS display property to `block` on mouseover, and `none` on mouseout. This will guarantee that the third level elements are hidden when they should be.

While I was sorting out the problem, I also reorganized part of the HTML and much of the CSS. There was a high number of overlapping and conflicting styles, which makes me amazed that it worked as well as it did.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="css/test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/ie7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!-- JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeBackground(oEl, iMode) {
    var sId = oEl.id;
    if (sId == null) alert("Your Element Does Not Have An ID!");

    if ((sId == 'menuAllProducts') || (sId == 'sub-menuAllProducts')) {
        if (iMode == 1) {
            document.getElementById('menuAllProducts').style.backgroundPosition='0px -35px';
            document.getElementById('menuAllProducts').style.height = "46px";
        } else if (iMode == 2) {
            document.getElementById('menuAllProducts').style.backgroundPosition='0px 0px';
            document.getElementById('menuAllProducts').style.height = "35px";
        }
    } else if ((sId == 'menuCustomerResources') || (sId == 'sub-menuCustomerResources')) {
        if (iMode == 1) {
            document.getElementById('menuCustomerResources').style.backgroundPosition='0px -35px';
            document.getElementById('menuCustomerResources').style.height = "46px";
        } else if (iMode == 2) {
            document.getElementById('menuCustomerResources').style.backgroundPosition='0px 0px';
            document.getElementById('menuCustomerResources').style.height = "35px";
        }
    } else if ((sId == 'menuPowerMaxAttitude') || (sId == 'sub-menuPowerMaxAttitude')) {
        if (iMode == 1) {
            document.getElementById('menuPowerMaxAttitude').style.backgroundPosition='0px -35px';
            document.getElementById('menuPowerMaxAttitude').style.height = "46px";
        } else if (iMode == 2) {
            document.getElementById('menuPowerMaxAttitude').style.backgroundPosition='0px 0px';
            document.getElementById('menuPowerMaxAttitude').style.height = "35px";
        }
    } else if ((sId == 'menuShippingPayment') || (sId == 'sub-menuShippingPayment')) {
        if (iMode == 1) {
            document.getElementById('menuShippingPayment').style.backgroundPosition='0px -35px';
            document.getElementById('menuShippingPayment').style.height = "46px";
        } else if (iMode == 2) {
            document.getElementById('menuShippingPayment').style.backgroundPosition='0px 0px';
            document.getElementById('menuShippingPayment').style.height = "35px";
        }
    } 
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="header">
<div id="nav">
<ul id="menu">
  <li class="menu-item" onMouseOver="changeBackground(document.getElementById('menuAllProducts'), 1);" onMouseOut="changeBackground(document.getElementById('menuAllProducts'), 2);">
    <div id="menuAllProducts">
      <a href="#">All Products</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="sub-menu" id="sub-menuAllProducts">
      <li class="sub-item" onmouseover="document.getElementById('third-menuNewMacs').style.display='block'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('third-menuNewMacs').style.display='none'">
        <a href="#">New Macs</a>
        <div id="third-menuNewMacs" class="third-menu">
          <div class="bkg"></div>
          <div class="arrow"><img src="/images/nav/arrow_head.png" /></div>
          <div class="newMacsOptions">
            <ul class="menuMacBookPro">
              <li><img src="/images/nav/icons/macbook_pro.png" /></li>
              <li><a href="#">MacBook Pro: 13"</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">MacBook Pro: 15"</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Macbook Pro: 17"</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="menuMacBookAir">
              <li><img src="/images/nav/icons/macbook_air.png" /></li>
              <li><a href="#">MacBook Air: 11"</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">MacBook Air: 13"</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="menuIMac">
              <li><img src="/images/nav/icons/imac.png" /></li>
              <li><a href="#">iMac: 21.5"</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">iMac: 27"</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="menuMacMini">
              <li><img src="/images/nav/icons/mac_mini.png" /></li>
              <li><a href="#">Mac mini</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Servers</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="menuMacPro">
              <li><img src="/images/nav/icons/mac_pro.png" /></li>
              <li><a href="#">Mac Pro</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="sub-item" onmouseover="document.getElementById('third-menuUsedMacs').style.display='block'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('third-menuUsedMacs').style.display='none'">
        <a href="#">Used Macs</a>
        <div id="third-menuUsedMacs" class="third-menu">
          <div class="bkg"></div>
          <div class="arrow"><img src="/images/nav/arrow_head.png" /></div>
          <ul>
            <li><h5>Desktops / Xserve</h5></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mac Pro</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">G5 Power Mac - PCI-E</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">G5 Power Mac - PCI-x</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">G5 Power Mac - PCI</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">G4 Power Mac Towers</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mac Mini - G4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">XServe - Intel</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">XServe - G5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">XServe - G4</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul>
            <li><h5>iMacs / eMac</h5></li>
            <li><a href="#">Intel iMac: 27-inch</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Intel iMac: 21.5-inch</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Intel iMac: 24-inch</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Intel iMac: 20-inch</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Intel iMac: 17-inch</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">G5 iMac: 20-inch</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">G5 iMac: 17-inch</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">G4 iMac: 20-inch</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">G4 iMac: 17-inch</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">G4 iMac: 15-inch</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">eMac</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul>
            <li><h5>MacBook / MacBook Pro</h5></li>
            <li><a href="#">Intel iMac: 27-inch</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Intel iMac: 21.5-inch</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Intel iMac: 24-inch</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Intel iMac: 20-inch</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Intel iMac: 17-inch</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">G5 iMac: 20-inch</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">G5 iMac: 17-inch</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">G4 iMac: 20-inch</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">G4 iMac: 17-inch</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">G4 iMac: 15-inch</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">eMac</a></li>
          </ul>

          <ul>
            <li><h5>iBook / PowerBooks</h5></li>
            <li><a href="#">Intel iMac: 27-inch</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Intel iMac: 21.5-inch</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Intel iMac: 24-inch</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Intel iMac: 20-inch</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Intel iMac: 17-inch</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">G5 iMac: 20-inch</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">G5 iMac: 17-inch</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">G4 iMac: 20-inch</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">G4 iMac: 17-inch</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">G4 iMac: 15-inch</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">eMac</a></li>
          </ul>
          <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="sub-item" onmouseover="" onmouseout="">
        <a href="#" id="menuSpecialValueMacs">Special Value Macs</a>
      </li>
      <li class="sub-item" onmouseover="" onmouseout="">
        <a href="#" id="menuCustomMacs">Custom Macs</a>
      </li>
      <li class="sub-item" onmouseover="" onmouseout="">
        <a href="#" id="menuiPods">iPods</a>
      </li>
      <li class="sub-item" onmouseover="" onmouseout="">
        <a href="#" id="menuiPads">iPads</a>
      </li>
      <li class="sub-item" onmouseover="" onmouseout="">
        <a href="#" id="menuStorage">Storage</a>
      </li>
      <li class="sub-item" onmouseover="" onmouseout="">
        <a href="#" id="menuDisplays">Displays</a>
      </li>
      <li class="sub-item" onmouseover="" onmouseout="">
        <a href="#" id="menuVideoAudio">Video+Audio</a>
      </li>
      <li class="sub-item" onmouseover="" onmouseout="">
        <a href="#" id="menuAccessories">Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li class="sub-item" onmouseover="" onmouseout="">
        <a href="#" id="menuNetworking">Networking</a>
      </li>
      <li class="sub-item" onmouseover="" onmouseout="">
        <a href="#" id="menuSoftware">Software</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="/images/nav/click_to_chat.png" /></a>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/* CSS Document */
h5 {font-family:'FranklinGothicLT-BookCnd', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:normal;color:#ff8e04;text-transform:uppercase;letter-spacing:-1px;margin:0; }
img{border:none;}
/* HEADER */
#header {
    position:relative;
    z-index:100;
    padding-bottom:38px;
}

/* NAVIGATION */
#nav {
    width:965px;
    position:absolute;
}
#menu {
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.menu-item {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    line-height:30px;
}
.menu-item:hover .sub-menu {
    display: block;
}
#menuAllProducts {
    position:relative;
    width:110px;
    height:35px;
    z-index:100;
    text-indent:-9000px;
    margin-right:4px;
    background:url(/images/nav/all_products.png) no-repeat;
}
.sub-menu {
    position:absolute;
    top:45px;
    left:0;
    width:199px;
    z-index:50;
    display:none;
    list-style:none;
    padding:10px 0 0;
    margin:0;
    background:#ff8e04;
    border:solid 1px #a3a3a3;
    box-shadow:3px 4px 10px -3px #555454;
}

    .sub-item {position:relative;height:26px;line-height:30px;padding-left:10px;background:url(/images/background/nav_dropdown.png) no-repeat;}
    .sub-item:hover {background:#fcba00;}
    .sub-item:hover .third-menu {display: block;}
    .sub-item a {color:#ff8e04;text-decoration:none;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-weight:bold;font-size:12px;}
    .sub-item:hover a {color:#fff;}

    .third-menu {position:absolute;top:-26px;right:-752px;width:750px;display:none;list-style:none;padding:0;margin:0;background:#f7f7f7;border:solid 1px #a3a3a3;box-shadow: 3px 4px 10px -3px #555454;}
    .third-menu ul {float:left;margin:0;padding:5px 10px;list-style:none;line-height:100%;width:160px;}
    .third-menu li {height:auto;line-height:20px;color:#595858;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-weight:bold;font-size:12px;}
    .third-menu li h5{color:#ff8e04;border-bottom:solid 1px #cbcbca;}
    .third-menu li a, 
    .third-menu li a:link, 
    .third-menu li a:active{color:#6a6a6a;text-decoration:none;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-weight:normal;font-size:11px;} 
    .third-menu li a:hover{color:#6a6a6a;text-decoration:underline;}
    .third-menu .bkg{background:#b8b7b6;height:10px;}

    #third-menuNewMacs {top:0;right:-470px; width:468px;height:151px;background:url(/images/background/nav_newmacs.png) no-repeat;}
    #third-menuNewMacs ul {float:left;margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none;line-height:100%;width:100px;}
    #third-menuNewMacs ul.menuMacMini {width:65px;}
    #third-menuNewMacs li {height:auto;line-height:20px;color:#595858;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-weight:bold;font-size:12px;text-align:center;}
    #third-menuNewMacs li a,
    #third-menuNewMacs li a:link,
    #third-menuNewMacs li a:active {color:#35cffa;text-decoration:none;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-weight:normal;font-size:11px;} 
    #third-menuNewMacs li a:hover {text-decoration:underline;}
    #third-menuNewMacs .arrow {position:absolute;top:0;left:-2px;}

    #third-menuUsedMacs {top:-26px;right:-752px;width:750px;}
    #third-menuUsedMacs .arrow {position:absolute;top:27px;left:-2px;}

    #menuCustomerResources{background:url(/images/nav/customer_resources.png) no-repeat;width:112px;height:35px;z-index:100;position:relative;text-indent:-9000px;margin-right:4px;}
    #menuPowerMaxAttitude{background:url(/images/nav/attitude_fun.png) no-repeat;width:130px;height:35px;z-index:100;position:relative;text-indent:-9000px;margin-right:4px;}
    #menuShippingPayment{background:url(/images/nav/shipping_payment.png) no-repeat;width:173px;height:35px;z-index:100;position:relative;text-indent:-9000px;margin-right:4px;}

.stretch,.clear {clear: both;height: 1px;margin: 0;padding: 0;font-size: 15px;line-height: 1px;}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I also thanks for orginizing the CSS. I guess I was so worried about getting it to work, I didn't realize how many styles I was repeating. Thanks Again!